# how can I stream MySQL database records in Flutter via PHP api?

Tags: mysql, flutter

I have created my own PHP api for getting and deleting data from database but I want realtime change like firestore database.
So how can I listen for data changes in MySQL database? I know stream is the way but how to apply it in Flutter App.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: @Texv Not yet, I tried to switch to firebase.

Comment: Very interesting question. I'm wondering the same thing. I think part of the problem is how to listen for MySQL changes (and signal them to PHP) which is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510554/how-to-get-real-time-changes-into-a-mysql-database-database-and-have-instant-res

Answer (score 1):

Use a [replication library](https://github.com/yerofey/replicator) and connect to the mysql server as a slave.

This will give you a feed of all database chagnes.

Comment: The library you are suggesting is performing action in every second as I seen by given link on GitHub Readme.md file. That I can do myself but I want realtime changes.

Comment: Apologies, I was assuming it was a realtime replication library like https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication . I also didn't requite realize it was so new. I'll let you search for a php equivalent or move using to using python (recommended for improving coding anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation @danblack. I will definitely give it a try on some other day because I am working for a client project right now and I don't have knowledge of python. It will be appreciated if any solution for MySQL DB via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When i wanted to do a similar thing
i created a function that gets the data from database
then used a timer to call the function every 3 seconds.
After every three seconds the updated ui is rebuilt.

Dont forget to check if the page is mounted and also to dispose the timer

This is What i did

```
Timer timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    refreshProductQuantity();
  });
});
```