# How to get real time changes into a MySql Database,Database and have instant response in frontend

Tags: mysql, express, sockets, real-time-updates

I am trying to build a simple project online. I have a MySql Database,Database where I will store different information, such as fake orders made from fake clients. The application will be formed by a frontend made with Javascript and HTML/CSS, while the backend will be a Node/Express API that should handle all the requests and handle the database.

I wanted to know whether there is a way to, each time a new order is made, have a refresh in my own page, and see, for example, a new column in an hypotetical table in my HTML with a minumum latency, avoiding making a request from the client every x seconds. This because it could be quite expensive in terms of bandwith and also prett unefficient.

I thought that each time I connect to the site, I get subscribed to a sort of list in the server, that broadcast a trigger to then update the frontend when tha UPDATE function is triggered in the backend. In other words, every time an update is done on the backend, the server sends a trigger to the clients that he knows are currently connected. Then, the frontend asks for the update directly.

This solutions  i really complicated to handle and may be not that performant. I was thinking if there where some functionalities of the frontend or the backend or the database, or any framework that allow me to do this thing.

I would like to have all as real time as possible, using the least bandwith possible. This is because I would like to use the free tier of some online service, and I don't want to consume all the bandwith.

If you have some suggestions of framework or functionalities, or any protocol, you are welcome. Thank you a lot in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use websockets. When a user creates an order and after there is a success saving to the data base, the backend will push or publish the data to the client who is subscribed to a specific channel. The logic is not complicated at all it is called the pub/sub pattern you should search for it.
Also https://socket.io/ this is library that used on both backend and front end to deal with websockets.